# return images from folder to flask

Tags: python, flask

I have several images in a folder which I want to upload to my flask app.

When I upload I am presented with a broken image and just the one rather than all 10 pictures I want to upload.

Ive made a image2.html page containing

and included the tag in my interface.html

```
for i in range(1):
    path = "/Users/devops/Desktop/Adversarial_Example_Project/static"

    random = np.random.random([200, 200, 3])
    #random[0:, 0:,0:]= 0
    random[ 150:200, 170:220, :]= [0.5,0.1,0.5]
    random[ 200:400, 170:220, :]= [0.1,0.3,0.6]
    random_image_location = path + '/adv/noise_00' + str(i) + '.jpg'
    imsave(random_image_location, random)

    clean_image = Image.open(image_path)
    noise_image = Image.open(random_image_location)

    clean_image = changeImageSize(200, 200, clean_image)
    noise_image = changeImageSize(200, 200, noise_image)


    clean_image = clean_image.convert("RGBA")
    noise_image = noise_image.convert("RGBA")
    adv_images = []

    for alpha_val in np.arange(0, 1, 0.1):
        percent =round( alpha_val *100)
        Advimg = Image.blend(clean_image, noise_image, alpha=alpha_val)
        adv_img_path = path + '/adv/adv' + str(i) + '-' + str(percent) + ".PNG"
        Advimg.save(adv_img_path, "PNG")
        adv_images.append(adv_img_path)

        print("Noise applied by " +str(percent)+  "% to images")
```

I would like to visualise all images saved in adv_images on my flask web app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the url_for template in flask instead of image.open:

```
{{ url_for(‘<yourimagefolder>’, filename=‘<yourimgname>’ }}
```